# how to extract key value pairs and assign the value to a variable in bash script

Tags: awk, key-value

For example I have the following in my script file

```
info="{FirstName=Tom;LastName=White;Gender=Male;Status=Married;}"
```

am looking to extract the key:vale and to assign the values to a variable

```
first_name=[FirstName]
last_name=[LastName]
gender=[Gender]
status=[Status]
```

and finally, to get the values from the variables for further processing:

```
echo $first_name = Tom
echo $last_name = White
echo $gender = Male
echo $status = Married

echo $info | awk -F'[{};=]' '{for(i=2;i<NF-1;i+=2) print $i ":" $(i+1)}'
```

would print the key: value, but am not able to store the values in another variable and to use for further processing

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you put the input into code blocks too, as it is not clear if the input is all on the same line or multiple lines? Also, the part where you talk about assigning the values to variables is not clear (to me at least) - are you wanting this to be done in bash or some other language?

Comment: Yes, am looking to have this done in bash ; am going to update the description

Comment: `eval "${info:1: -1}"; echo "$FirstName"` Please become familiar with the risks associated with `eval`.

Comment: is this a bash question or an awk question?